# Navigation command withing viewCell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a custom `ViewCell`. I was wondering if I could add a command to it, which would navigate to another page, when the `ViewCell` is clicked.

Below is what I have so far:

```
public class MainMenuItem : ViewCell
{
    public MainMenuItem(string text, string icon)
    {
        View = new StackLayout()
        {
            Spacing = 10,
            Padding = 10,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                new Image() {
                    Source = ImageSource.FromFile(icon),
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    HeightRequest = 30,
                    WidthRequest = 30,
                },
                new Label() {
                    Text = text,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    FontSize = 18,
                },
                 new Image() {
                    Source = ImageSource.FromFile("listitem_next.png"),
                    HeightRequest = 12,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
                }
            }
        };

        View = View;
    }
}
```

Above is my view cell. Now I render these within Table sections of a `TableView`. And here is the code for that:

```
TableView tvProfile = new TableView
{
    HasUnevenRows = true,
    Intent = TableIntent.Form,
    Root = new TableRoot {,
            new TableSection ("Emergency Contacts")
            {
                new MainMenuItem("Contacts", "icon_phone.png")
            },
            new TableSection ("Check in Timers")
            {
                new MainMenuItem("Timers", "icon_clock.png")
            },
            new TableSection ("Medical Information")
            {
                new MainMenuItem("Medcial Info", "icon_medicalkit.png")
            }
        }
};
```

What I want is, when the user selects an Item (the `ViewCell`), I want to navigate the user to the respective page.

How do I do this using a command? If it's even possible. I'm new to using commands, so whatever I've gotten on the web has gone over my head.

Any help on this would be HUGELY appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick'n'dirty implementation. Add `command` and `commandParameter` to `constructor` and add `GestureRecognizer` which calls this `command`.

```
public class MainMenuItem : ViewCell
{
    public MainMenuItem(string text, string icon, ICommand command,  Func<Page> commandParameterFunc)
    {
        View = new StackLayout()
        {
            ...
        };

        View.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = command, CommandParameter = commandParameterFunc });
    }
}
```

Then do the following changes - create a command and add 2 parameters to every cell. Here you define the command, what happens when you click and a parameter for the command, which is a Page *(but you should not create it here already and check for errors)*.

**Update**: I changed to pass a function instead of an object, so the Page is created on click. Still a bit dirty ;)

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly ICommand _navigateCommand;

    public MyPage()
    {
        _navigateCommand = new Command(commandParamter => Navigation.PushModalAsync((commandParamter as Func<Page>)())));

        TableView tvProfile = new TableView
        {
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            Intent = TableIntent.Form,
            Root = new TableRoot 
            {
                new TableSection ("Emergency Contacts")
                {
                    new MainMenuItem("Contacts", "icon_phone.png", _navigateCommand, () => new ContactsPage())
                },
                new TableSection ("Check in Timers")
                {
                    new MainMenuItem("Timers", "icon_clock.png", _navigateCommand, () => new TimersPage())
                },
                new TableSection ("Medical Information")
                {
                    new MainMenuItem("Medcial Info", "icon_medicalkit.png", _navigateCommand, () => new MedicalInfoPage())
                }
            }
        };
        Content = tvProfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will see to cleaning it up a bit. But thank you again for pushing me in any direction.